# Multi Vlans with one DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

We have multiple vlans configured on Cisco 4506, two of them with dhcp enabled to serve living area inside our company and wireless.
I installed a new DHCP on windows server 2008 r2 and planning to cancel cisco's dhcp. Is it a good idea ?

Comment: Why not ? At first sight what leads you to setup and run another DHCP server ?

Comment: i think managing windows dhcp more simple than managing it at cisco

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 R2 includes a pretty good DHCP service, which has no problem at all serving multiple subnets (they are called "scopes" in DHCP jargon).

If your network is routed and you want a single DHCP server to provide network configuration to devices in multiple subnets, you will need to configure your router(s) to forward DHCP requests from the various networks to your central DHCP server(s); in Cisco routers, that would require configuring one or more "ip helper address".

Here's some documentation:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759218.aspx
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dhcp/configuration/12-4t/dhcp-12-4t-book/config-dhcp-relay-agent.html

---

If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask; but please try to avoid such generic questions as this one, because they are not a good fit for the Q&A format of this site and are thus very likely to be closed.

Comment: If the DHCP server is NOT also a Domain Controller, one suggestion might be to multi-home the DHCP server in order to service the clients on each VLAN without the need for a DHCP helper.

Comment: That would work; but a helper address definition on the router is a lot simpler.